# In a c# service with a longRunning Async main method, should you .wait in the service startup, store the Task somewhere, or ignore it entirely?

Tags: c#, service, async-await, constructor

In a lot of our services, the OnStart method calls a neverEnding async Task and .Wait() which does all the service work until it gets manually shut down. We do something like the following (and have been since before I came onto the scene).

```
MyServiceClass service;
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    eventLog.WriteEntry("MyService service is starting up.");
    service = new MyServiceClass(this.ServiceName);
}
...
public class MyServiceClass
{
    public MyServiceClass() {
        Task.Run(() => DoServiceWork()).Wait();
    }
    public async Task DoServiceWork() {
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);//pretend this is actual work being done
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any reason not to just store the task and move on? (assuming the main method has appropriate exception handling)

```
public class MyServiceClass
{
    public Task taskToBeAwaitedOnServiceStop;
    public MyServiceClass() {
        taskToBeAwaitedOnServiceStop = Task.Run(() => DoServiceWork());
    }
}
```

or just to ignore the task entirely

```
public class MyServiceClass
{
    public MyServiceClass() {
        _ = DoServiceWork();
    }
}
```

I'm considering the options as we don't like having .waits floating around (and having less means less to check when we go hunting). I'm asking here to be certain my alternatives won't cause strange service logic if implemented.

I hope this isn't too stupid a question, thanks for any help :)

Comment: IMHO if you find yourself writing a constructor with heavy CPU / IO, then you should either write a factory method, or just assume the caller will call your `DoWork` method.

Comment: Yes, doing heavy operations in constructor is a bad practice. Using `Task.Run()` should avoided as well and the body be moved to separate `async Task` method and continue this flow from the very beginning. Also if you will see the `.Wait()` in code, just refactor it as fast as possible :) The reason is, `Wait` will block the calling thread.